# Android - onNewIntent - fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, onnewintent

Which is the best way to handle a bundle with comes at `onNewIntent` method?

This arrow -> means push fragment.

I have the following scenario:

> ActivityA -> FragmentA -> FragmentB -> I go background -> I receive a
>   push notfication -> User clicks on the push notification which opens
>   the ActivityA with a bundle inside.

Then I receive a bundle on onNewIntent method, this bundle has data inside which tells me I have to show FragmentA.

One can suggest just unpop from the stack the fragmentB when you return from background. I don't want that approach, I want the first thing the user see in the screen when comes to background is FragmentA.

Comment: Unclear, what do you mean by `I don't want the visual effect that let the user see how Fragment B is poped to reach FragmentA.`

Comment: I have updated the question. what about now?